# Can I install spell-checking and other language support packages on Fedora without searching them?

Tags: fedora, package-management, language, spell-checking

I would like to learn the **canonical way for adding system-wide language support on Fedora** Workstation or confirm that there is none. I intend to preserve my interface language, but add all other associated language tools, such as spell-checking dictionaries, hyphenation assistance, etc. I know I can enable all of this by installing relevant individual packages manually, but I would like to rely on the distribution maintainers to decide what packages are necessary. Is such approach supported?

The Fedora documentation seems to cover only the [system locale and keyboard configuration](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f34/system-administrators-guide/basic-system-configuration/System_Locale_and_Keyboard_Configuration/), but not the spell-checking.

During Fedora installation, I specified Ukrainian as my system language. However, only English spell-checking was installed by default. `hunspell-uk` wasn't installed. For instance, in the GNOME text editor (`gedit`), there were only English spell-checking dictionaries. When I opened LibreOffice Writer for the first time, a system pop-up prompted for installation of additional packages, which completed automatically once confirmed. So, now, I have `hunspell-uk` and other packages for spell-checking and hyphenation in Ukrainian in LibreOffice, GNOME text editor, and in Firefox (after restart).

```
$ LC_ALL=C dnf history info 21
Transaction ID : 21
Begin time     : Sun Aug 29 19:17:00 2021
Begin rpmdb    : 1760:50e6a4d235a9a38ca4c583e8a47bd6091ec988c0
End time       : Sun Aug 29 19:17:01 2021 (1 seconds)
End rpmdb      : 1769:e7ecb46ec061ec5ad63f3c0b121ecb0e013a7ab3
User           : Roman Riabenko <roman>
Return-Code    : Success
Releasever     : 
Command Line   : 
Comment        : 
Packages Altered:
    Install glibc-langpack-uk-2.33-20.fc34.x86_64           @updates
    Install libreoffice-help-uk-1:7.1.5.2-5.fc34.x86_64     @updates
    Install libreoffice-langpack-uk-1:7.1.5.2-5.fc34.x86_64 @updates
    Install hunspell-uk-1.8.0-7.fc34.noarch                 @fedora
    Install hyphen-uk-0.20030903-22.fc34.noarch             @fedora
    Install langpacks-core-font-uk-3.0-14.fc34.noarch       @fedora
    Install langpacks-core-uk-3.0-14.fc34.noarch            @fedora
    Install langpacks-uk-3.0-14.fc34.noarch                 @fedora
    Install mythes-uk-1.6.5-20.fc34.noarch                  @fedora
```

For context, I will explain how I was dealing with it under Debian. With Debian, assuming I chose Ukrainian as my system language during installation, I get both English and Ukrainian support installed automatically out-of-the-box. I know that, during installation, the configuration is handled by `tasksel`. So, after installation, I can run `tasksel install russian russian-desktop`. It effectively installs metapackages `task-russian` and `task-russian-desktop` that rely on the necessary packages without me needing to learn or remember what are those packages. It seems to introduce some packages that I don't really need, like some converters that I never use, but I consider it to be a trade-off of relying on someone else for making an educated decision to cover most use cases. Is there any similar global configuration for language support on Fedora?

In GNOME settings, I added Russian as another input language, so that I could enter text from keyboard, but this did not bring spell-cheking. I could also change the language for the GUI, but I do not want to do that and it does not promise to provide spell-checking.

I found that there are `langpacks-*` in Fedora repositories, but, in case of `langpacks-uk` and `langpacks-ru`, the package brings only font packages and not spell-checking packages like `hunspell-ru`, `aspell-ru`, `hyphen-ru`, etc. Is it a bug?

```
$ LC_ALL=C dnf info langpacks-ru
Last metadata expiration check: 3:25:16 ago on Sat Sep 25 14:07:02 2021.
Installed Packages
Name         : langpacks-ru
Version      : 3.0
Release      : 14.fc34
Architecture : noarch
Size         : 400  
Source       : langpacks-3.0-14.fc34.src.rpm
Repository   : @System
From repo    : fedora
Summary      : Russian langpacks meta-package
License      : GPLv2+
Description  : This package provides Russian langpacks meta-package.

$ LC_ALL=C dnf repoquery --depends langpacks-ru
Last metadata expiration check: 2:36:48 ago on Sun Aug 29 19:05:55 2021.
langpacks-core-ru
pt-sans-fonts
$ LC_ALL=C dnf repoquery --depends langpacks-core-ru
Last metadata expiration check: 2:37:44 ago on Sun Aug 29 19:05:55 2021.
langpacks-core-font-ru
$ LC_ALL=C dnf repoquery --depends langpacks-core-font-ru
Last metadata expiration check: 2:36:48 ago on Sun Aug 29 19:05:55 2021.
dejavu-sans-fonts
```

I learned that I can list package groups available for installation with `dnf grouplist`, but there appears to be no language-specific groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing the respective `langpacks-*` package is the correct solution. In Fedora Workstation, it is possible just to reach out for "Activities", type in the language that you need, and go straightly to installing the pack in GNOME Software.

[image]

My problem was that I only checked for dependencies of the meta-package, concluded it to be irrelevant, and did not try installing it. The packages that I was looking for happened to be "weak" dependencies. I [started a new question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/670602/423679) to clarify why I did not see them.

Here is an example of what was installed for the Russian language.

```
$ LC_ALL=C dnf history info 53
Transaction ID : 53
Begin time     : Sat Sep 25 15:25:33 2021
Begin rpmdb    : 1923:5ed2042bece8a42f6774e1a69a2c1d3e73cf5d72
End time       : Sat Sep 25 15:25:37 2021 (4 seconds)
End rpmdb      : 1934:033d166658f519594bcc1ff0e85c3192530fac9b
User           : Roman Riabenko <roman>
Return-Code    : Success
Releasever     : 34
Command Line   : install langpacks-ru
Comment        : 
Packages Altered:
    Install hunspell-ru-1:0.99g5-19.fc34.noarch             @fedora
    Install hyphen-ru-0.20200325-2.fc34.noarch              @fedora
    Install langpacks-core-font-ru-3.0-14.fc34.noarch       @fedora
    Install langpacks-core-ru-3.0-14.fc34.noarch            @fedora
    Install langpacks-ru-3.0-14.fc34.noarch                 @fedora
    Install man-pages-ru-5.03-5.20191017.fc34.noarch        @fedora
    Install mythes-ru-0.20070613-23.fc34.noarch             @fedora
    Install autocorr-ru-1:7.1.6.2-1.fc34.noarch             @updates
    Install glibc-langpack-ru-2.33-20.fc34.x86_64           @updates
    Install libreoffice-help-ru-1:7.1.6.2-1.fc34.x86_64     @updates
    Install libreoffice-langpack-ru-1:7.1.6.2-1.fc34.x86_64 @updates
```